# How to reference associated models in a one-to-many relationship with Sails 0.10.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, associations, sails.js

I'm using `Sails.js` version 0.10.x, and am just starting to try out it's `associactions` stuff.

In my scenario I have a User who has many Documents.

so in `/api/models/User.js` I have:

```
module.exports = {
  // snipped out bcrypt stuff etc
  attributes: {
     email: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      required: true
    },
    documents: {
      collection: 'document',
      via: 'owner'
    },
  }
};
```

and in `/api/models/Document.js` I have:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name:      'string',
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
};
```

In my `DocumentController` I have the following:

```
fileData = {
  name: file.name,
  owner: req.user
}

Document.create(fileData).exec(function(err, savedFile){
  if (err) {
    next(err);
  } else {
    results.push({
      id: savedFile.id,
      url: '/files/' + savedFile.name,
      document: savedFile
    });
    next();
  }
});
```

Looking in my local `mongo` database via the command line I can see that the documents have the owner field set as follows `"owner" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")` which is as expected.

However when I inspect the `req.user` object later in the DocumentController via `sails.log.debug("user has documemts", req.user.documents);` I see

```
debug: user has documents [ add: [Function: add], remove: [Function: remove] ]
```

And not an array of `Document` objects.

In my resulting `slim` template

```
if req.user.documents.length > 0
  ul
    for doc in req.user.documents
      li= doc.toString()
else
  p No Documents!
```

I always get "No Documents!"

I seem to be missing something obvious but I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out by wading through the `Waterline` source code.

Firstly, as I hoped, both sides of the association are affected by the creation of the `Document` instance, and I simply needed to reload my user.

Within the controller this is as simple as `User.findOne(req.user.id).populateAll().exec(...)`

I also modified my `passport` service helper as follows

```
function findById(id, fn) {
  User.findOne(id).populateAll().exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return fn(null, null);
    return fn(null, user);
  });
}

function findByEmail(email, fn) {
  User.findOne({email: email}).populateAll().exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return fn(null, null);
    return fn(null, user);
  });
}
```

Now the `user`, and its associations, are loaded properly per request.

I had to dig through the source to find the `populateAll()` method as it's not actually documented anywhere I could find. I could also have used `populate('documents')` instead but I am about to add other associations to the User so need `populateAll()` to load all the relevant associations.

- [Waterline `associations` docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md)
- [Waterline `/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js#populateAll`](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js#L69)